# Is there a better way to access variables from one React component to another than just passing it through as parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a React component somewhat like this:

```
function App() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState("xyz");
  const var1 = "abc";
  const var2 = "def";

  function StepZero() {
    return <div>
       <p>{someValue}</p>
       <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
       <h1>{var1} {var2}</h1>
       <Button onClick={() => setSomeValue("123")}>Click</Button>
     </div>;
  }
  
  function StepOne() {
    return <div>
      <h1>{someValue}</h1>
      <Button onClick={() => setSomeValue("456")}>Click</Button>
      <h2>{var1}</h2>
      <h3>{var2}</h3>
    </div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {step === 0 ? (
          <StepZero />
        ) : (
          <StepOne />
        )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What happens here is, once someValue gets set, the whole StepZero gets re-rendered and the input lost. Really any user interaction gets reset, e.g. an accordion that got opened.
What resolves this is putting StepZero and StepOne directly into the return function, or putting them outside the App component and then passing all the variables in the params like:

```
{ var1, var2, someValue, setSomeValue }
```

Is there a better way to do this that I can separate the two steps into components while still being able to access the states and variables/constants, without state changes re-rendering the components every time, or without having to pass all the required variables as parameters?

*Note this example app isn't meant to do anything functionally useful*

Comment: Can you add a reproducible codesandbox link or something?

Comment: I myself am also new to React so I'm not entirely sure but I'm gonna suggest you separate the stepOne and stepZero functions out to components and pass the data like in the tutorial: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props Hope this helps, I'm trying to figure some functionality out myself too

Comment: I don't know what is the real problem, but there are many things you can do differently

- don't use state if not needed (like if you handling a simple form you can just read its values on submit)

- you can use a context (React) or Redux

- do not put your component constructors ("StepZero"/"StepOne") inside your main component ("App")

Answer (score 1):

Based on react architecture passing states and variables through props is the best solution.

Now, based on what you requested I have multiple suggestion:

- if the constants are resetting, have you tried to save the constants in a ref? (for ex: const var1 = useRef("abc");)
- if you don't want to pass data as props but you want them to share the same variables, you can either add Redux ([React-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)) or use React Context ([How to use React Context](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-react-context-to-share-data-between-components))
- But if you're project isn't big, i'd suggest you pass them as props, similar to the following:

In the parent App component:

```
 const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState("xyz");
  const var1 = useRef("abc");
  const var2 = useRef("def");
```

---

And in a separate component

```
      function StepZero({someValue,var1,var2,setSomeValue}) {
    return <div>
       <p>{someValue}</p>
       <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
       <h1>{var1.current} {var2.current}</h1>
       <Button onClick={() => setSomeValue("123")}>Click</Button>
     </div>;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, last-mentioned is exactly what I'm doing right now. I have used refs before, but found they don't work if you're using the variable in more than one place.

Comment: I personally never faced an issue by sharing a useRef variable throughout different components, So in your case there must be something affecting them, thus, try debugging with console.log in order to know when the variable is affected

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know more about how reactjs its work, and base on that you can go...the main idea you need start think about that react is Component-Based, and thats mean "Build encapsulated components that manage their own state"

so, from this point you can know that we have component which its has a control to manage their state, so this will move to next step..

At first level, we have props, state and context, which all of these concepts will help you to pass/share data

1- Props will used to pass data from higher component to nested component, and its immutable

2- State will track your value change and you can updated it to update needed functions...

3- Context which its used to share data between multiple component without passing a props from higher one to lowest one...

After we know about these details, we need to go to step two, which we need to understand Re-render...
The render spitted to initial render which happens when a component first appears on the screen and re-render happens when React needs to update the app with some new data, and usually its happen base on action or interactive action...
Note: react handle the re-render and know which spesfic part is render and handling to re-render it, its virtual dom and can be controlled very well...

Now lets go to your code:

1- You can pass your details as props, and you can split App component to small component:

```
function StepZero(props) {
        return <div>
           <p>{props.someValue}</p>
           <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
           <h1>{var1} {var2}</h1>
           <Button onClick={() => props.setSomeValue("123")}>Click</Button>
         </div>;
      }
      
      function StepOne(props) {
        return <div>
          <h1>{props.someValue}</h1>
          <Button onClick={() => props.setSomeValue("456")}>Click</Button>
          <h2>{var1}</h2>
          <h3>{var2}</h3>
        </div>;
      }

function App() {
      const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
      const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState("xyz");
      const var1 = "abc";
      const var2 = "def";
    
      return (
        <div>
            {step === 0 ? (
              <StepZero {youProps}/>
            ) : (
              <StepOne {youProps}/>
            )}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

The second solution is use content [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

For re-render you need to handling update dependency correctly and if its in loop or list you need to add [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)
Also, **you must know that var1 and var2 will keep re-render since its set direct without state**, ref and its put directly in component not a static / const out side the component, so each time you re-render the component its will has a new memory address which its mean a new re-render for any place has lisen to it...

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've assumed and have been doing. I will use context in the future too, but it's a bit of a hassle.

Comment: You are welcome, and thats correct, you need to handling it very well to got the benfits from context and use it only when you needed it...to prevent un-needed re-render, also you must read about useCallback and useMemo which will help you to prevent re-renders

Answer (score 0):

First all your child components have to be outside your App function, in order of having their own state.
Secondly you will pass the *somevalue* state to all your child in a props and lift the state up to your parent with a callback function.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Something like this (I simplified your code for the example)

```
function StepZero({val,var1,var2,callback}) {
    return <div>
       <p>{val}</p>
       <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
       <h1>{var1} {var2}</h1>
       <Button onClick={() => callback("123")}>Click</Button>
     </div>;
  }

function App() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState("xyz");
  const var1 = "abc";
  const var2 = "def";
  return (
    <div>        
       <StepZero val={someValue} var1={var1} var2={var2} callback={setSomeValue} />        
    </div>
  );
}
```